# Why does the search module break cron

Tags: search, cron

I was trying to work out why cron wouldn't run on my site and came across this post: http://codekarate.com/blog/drupal-6-fixing-stuck-cron-run which said that enabling and disabling search would fix it. It did, but does anyone know why search breaks cron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Search module implements `hook_cron()`, and its implementation it invokes [hook_update_index()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_update_index/6) to update the search index. One of that hook implementations is [node_update_index()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_update_index/6), which

- Loads some nodes whose IDs are returned from a query
- Renders those nodes, and passes their body content to [search_index()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.module/function/search_index/6)

If the node body contains PHP code that redirects the users to a different page, or an implementation of `hook_nodeapi()` redirects the users when a node is viewed, that can cause problems to cron tasks.